# Show $a_{n+1} \geq \sqrt{B}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_0$ and $B$ are positive numbers , define a sequence $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(a_n +B/a_n)$. Show that $a_{n+1} \geq\sqrt B$.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the AM-GM inequality:
$$
a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\Big(a_n+\frac{B}{a_n}\Big)\geq\sqrt{a_nB/a_n}=\sqrt{B}.
$$
For strict rigor, you should make a quick induction argument to show that $a_n>0$ for all $n$. To see that $a_{n+1}\geq B$ is tight, see what happens when $a_0=\sqrt{B}$.